# Spring data jpa - compicated query

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I am trying to prepare compliacted query using Spring Data JPA.

```
Page<Line> findByIdIn_AndNumberIgnoreCaseContainingAndActualTrueAndOrNameIgnoreCaseContainingInAndActualTrueOrderById(List<Long> idList, String number, String name, Pageable pageable);
```

My goal is to build query like:

```
select * from line where id in (?,?,?) and (number like ? and actual = true) or (name like ? and actual = true) order by id
```

Unfortunately I have following error:

```
No property in found for type Long! Traversed path: Line.id.
```

Whats wrong with my method name?

And also I made a method:

```
Page<Line> findByNumberIgnoreCaseContainingAndActualTrueOrNameIgnoreCaseContainingAndActualTrueOrderById(String number, String name, Pageable pageable);
```

And that one works good. The problem is with id in..

Comment: why did you have underscore after in keyword. Underscore is used reach sub elements of object in jpa. This can cause the issue. Can you post your Line model? It can give more insight.

Comment: I tried to create only `Page<Line> findByIdIn(List<Long> ids, Pageable pageable);` but the problem is same